# Packaging electron js app and getting white screen when I run the executable

Tags: reactjs, electron

I'm trying to distribute my electron js app in order to get a .exe file, the build is done but once I run it I get a white screen with no errors in the console.

Actually my app is an electron js appp build on top of a react js app. I'm using sqlite database and making connection to reactjs app to display data etc..
To make it clear, this is how I run my desktop app:

```
concurrently  \"cross-env BROWSER=none PORT=3000 parcel\" \"wait-on http://localhost:3000 && electron .\"
```

and this is how I did the .exe build:

```
npm install -g electron-packager --save-dev
```

and:

```
electron-packager . MyApp2 --platform=win32 --arch=x64 --out=release-builds
```

I changed `BrowserRouter` by `HashRouter` and added   `"homepage": "./",`
at package.json, got the following error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' at src/index.js
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [packaging an electron App results in an empty UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77345120/packaging-an-electron-app-results-in-an-empty-ui)

Comment: I did that and I got an error in my console.log: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'

at src/index.js (updating my post)

Comment: This is another problem and therefore it should be another question (but **search first before asking a new question**), your initial issue was resolved with the duplicate and so should be marked a such.