# Electron with React: blank page

Tags: reactjs, electron

i need help with the blank page issue with electron and react.
I tried for 2 days without success.
I can't understand why electron loads css and js but don't load the app.
I am also using react router.
I don't recieve any error.

Here my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "srfotosessions",
  "main": "electron-main.js",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "description": "La tua descrizione dell'app",
  "author": "LS",
  "homepage": "./",
  "build": {
    "appId": "com.esempio.app",
    "productName": "NomeApp",
    "directories": {
      "buildResources": "build"
    },
    "dmg": {
      "title": "${productName} ${version}"
    }
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining": "^7.21.0",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-optional-chaining": "^7.23.4",
    "@electron/remote": "^2.1.1",
    "@emotion/react": "^11.11.3",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.11.0",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.15.6",
    "@mui/joy": "^5.0.0-beta.24",
    "@mui/material": "^5.15.6",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^2.1.0",
    "@scena/guides": "^0.29.2",
    "@scena/react-guides": "^0.28.2",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.17.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "axios": "^1.6.5",
    "bootstrap": "^5.3.2",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "electron-is-dev": "^3.0.1",
    "electron-squirrel-startup": "^1.0.0",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.5",
    "gesto": "^1.19.4",
    "html2canvas": "^1.4.1",
    "i": "^0.3.7",
    "jimp": "^0.22.10",
    "npm": "^10.4.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "^2.10.0",
    "react-dnd": "^16.0.1",
    "react-dnd-html5-backend": "^16.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-image-crop": "^11.0.5",
    "react-redux": "^9.1.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.21.3",
    "react-scripts": "^3.0.1",
    "socket.io-client": "^4.7.4",
    "uuid": "^9.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "export NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider && react-scripts start",
    "build": "export NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider && react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "electron": "electron .",
    "pack": "electron-builder --dir",
    "dist": "electron-builder"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.23.7",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.23.8",
    "@electron-forge/cli": "^7.2.0",
    "@electron-forge/maker-deb": "^7.2.0",
    "@electron-forge/maker-rpm": "^7.2.0",
    "@electron-forge/maker-squirrel": "^7.2.0",
    "@electron-forge/maker-zip": "^7.2.0",
    "@electron-forge/plugin-auto-unpack-natives": "^7.2.0",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "electron": "28.2.1",
    "electron-builder": "^24.9.1"
  }
}
```

here my electron-main.js

```
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require("electron");
const path = require("path");
const url = require("url");
function createWindow() {
  const startUrl =
    process.env.ELECTRON_START_URL ||
    url.format({
      pathname: path.join(__dirname, "build/index.html"),
      protocol: "file:",
      slashes: true,
    });
  const win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 800,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true,
    },
  });
  win.loadURL(startUrl);
  app.on("window-all-closed", () => {
    if (process.platform !== "darwin") {
      app.quit();
    }
  });
}
app.whenReady().then(createWindow);
app.on("window-all-closed", () => {
  if (process.platform !== "darwin") {
    app.quit();
  }
});
app.on("activate", () => {
  if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) {
    createWindow();
  }
});
```

[image]

this is when i use electron .

blank page, i can't understand!

I am expecting electron loading static files.
I need then buil app for osx using electron-builder

Comment: Does this answer your question? [packaging an electron App results in an empty UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77345120/packaging-an-electron-app-results-in-an-empty-ui)

Comment: yes, but now i have another problem: it gives me net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND on index.html when i launch the dist app. i changed some settings and now i am stuck here

Comment: You will have to ask a new question with the relevant information, this one is a duplicate.